# Session-in-view and TransactionScope

Tags: .net, asp.net, nhibernate, transactions

we have a asp.net webforms app using NHibernate. Here are some specifics:

- We need Distributed Transactions because we write to the database as well as to a queue.
- Because this is a web app, we use the recomended Session-in-view pattern. We have a HTTPModule that opens the NHibernate session on the BeginRequest event and closes it on EndRequest.
- Within the flow of a request, we have several separate moments where we need to do transactional work. For this, we use TransactionScope.

So basically, what happens is this (pseudocode):

```
using(var session = sessionFactory.CreateSession()){
  using(var tx1 = new TransactionScope(){
    //work work work
    tx1.Complete();
  }

  //other work

  using(var tx2 = new TransactionScope(){
    //work work work
    tx2.Complete();
  }
}
```

However we now get into a situation where we see a lot of crashes related to the Connection to the database. Some researching gave us two suggestions:

- Use a NHibernate transaction within your transactionscope
- Create your session within your transactionscope

However, we have two questions about these suggestions:

1. Doesn't NHibernate automatically enlist itself into the TransactionScope. Why do we need to create a transaction explicitly for NHibernate?
2. If we must create our Session within the TransactionScope, how can we combine this with the Session-in-view pattern?

Answer (score 4):

- You **must** use NH transactions (`session.BeginTransaction()`)
- NH ***transactions*** will automatically enlist in the TransactionScope
- You don't have to create your session inside the TransactionScope.

Comment: Can you also tell me why? All the examples I find create the session within the TransactionScope.

Comment: That's just how it works (call it an implementation detail). I don't know where you've seen those examples (link?), but if they create sessions and not NH transactions, they are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [ncommon framework](https://github.com/riteshrao/ncommon), it demonstrates a method of using NHibernate with a TransactionScope using the concept of a `UnitOfWorkScope`; this may be the guidance that you're looking for.